# C2039: 'exit' : is not a member of '`global namespace'

Tags: c++

Подробнее. Пишу в Microsoft Visual Studio 2010:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World!";
}
```

На что компилятор выдаёт:

```
error C2039: 'exit' : is not a member of '`global namespace'
error C2873: 'exit' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
```

Ссылается на *cstdlib*. В чем проблема?

Comment: На какой строчке он выдает ошибку? Если в другом файле, покажите и его.

Comment: Это единственный файл программы. Ошибку выдает в библиотеке cstdlib.

Error 1 error C2039: 'exit' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdlib 24 1 Prog

Вот полностью скопированный код ошибки.

Comment: Какая версия ОСи?

Comment: Windows 7 Professional x64

Comment: Пробовали вместо <iostream> писать <iostream.h>?

Comment: Дело не в iostream.

Comment: Так пробовали или нет? Сначала надо пробовать, затем писать. Вот если Вы делаете пустой проект, и там такая ошибка -- тогда я понимаю, а тут сначала дело, затем слово. И потом, второй вариант -- поставьте себе Студию х64, а не х86, и будет много счастья...

Answer (score 1):

Сталкивался с подобной ошибкой, помогло небольшое изменение `stdlib.h`.
Найдите закомменченную строчку:

```
_CRTIMP __declspec(noreturn) void __cdecl exit(__in int _Code);
```

и снимите комментарий.

Comment: Загадочное решение, но плюсадын.

Comment: Подобно автору, я юзаю MVS 2010, но такой строчки в  stdlib.h я не нашел. Есть иная конструкция:

sharp ifndef _CRT_TERMINATE_DEFINED

sharp define _CRT_TERMINATE_DEFINED

_CRTIMP __declspec(noreturn) void __cdecl exit(_In_ int _Code);

_CRTIMP __declspec(noreturn) void __cdecl _exit(_In_ int _Code);

_CRTIMP void __cdecl abort(void);

sharp endif

Sharp я писал вместо решетки...

Answer (score 0):

Это все кривой майкрософтовский компилятор. Используйте gcc.

Либо пробуйте колдовать с включениями (попробуйте вначале программы написать #include <cstdlib> или #include <stdlib.h>). Как вариант поможет вначале using std::exit.

P.S. решения подсмотрены в гугле

Comment: Варианты подсмотреные в гугле не работают. exit не относится к пространству std. Библиотеки подключал и по-отдельности и вместе, результат не изменился. GCC могу использовать, но интересно, что случилось с MVS и как это исправить.

Comment: Так и у меня раньше все компилировалось, а теперь, по неведомым причинам, стал выдавать ошибки.

Comment: Тогда попробуйте переустановить среду.... Вдруг поможет.

Comment: С переустановкой MVS среда переустанавливалась тоже, но это не помогло.

Comment: >Это все кривой майкрософтовский компилятор. Используйте gcc.

 Ага, и он выдаст этот helloworld экзешником в 1 МБ.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте просто скопировать этот файл с диска, с которого была установлена студия, вручную, с заменой. Или возьмите где-нибудь другой такой файл, но только для среды, сходной с Вашей.

Answer (score 0):

Нашлось решение. В cstdlib.h комментируется строка `/*using _CSTD exit;*/` и все работает.